# How would I differentiate between different types of exceptions?

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to learn JavaScript, so far no problem but I have a hard time finding a good explanation of the Exception mechanism in JS.

It seems similar to C++, JS allows to throw about every object, instead of just throwing an Exception object (probably due to it's dynamic nature).

```
throw 'An error occured.';
```

works, as well as

```
throw new Exception('An error occured.');
```

`catch` and `finally` both seem to work like their Java equivalent. Still, I don't know what are widely accepted best practices regarding exceptions.

So, for example, is it legit to throw objects of type string, like:

```
throw 'An error occured';
```

How would I differentiate between different types of exceptions?

Comment: You'll have to narrow your question down. Best practices in terms of what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Throwing and catching exceptions is pretty expensive, and with JavaScript, you're primarily going to get exceptions in cases like when you try to parse a JSON string that is malformatted. I would suggest avoiding try/catch as much as possible and instead focus on checking for errors the old fashion way (return types, making sure variables are properly initialized before using them, etc.) since exceptions are less likely to happen here than in C++ or especially Java or .NET.

[Andy E's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987321/320399) is a good one for actually handling them, but in general, you should try to write JavaScript code defensively so that you don't even need try/catch. Remember, even JITed JavaScript in Chrome (fastest engine) is still slow as heck compared to Java or C#, to say nothing of C++, so anything that is expensive in those languages is likely to be even more so in JavaScript.

Comment: +1, it didn't occur to me to recommend against try/catch statements altogether, even though I rarely ever need to write one.  One of the reasons you might need a try/catch are when dealing with host objects (like IE's `ActiveXObjects`) that may not be present or unable to be instantiated.

Answer (score 17):

The "best practice", I suppose, is to throw the correct type of Error object related to the problem causing the exception.  ECMAScript defines several types of exception object, all of which inherit from `Error`.  These objects are `EvalError`, `RangeError`, `ReferenceError`, `TypeError` and `URIError`.

Those constructors are used by native ECMAScript functions, which enables you to do something like this:

```
try {
    // do something
}
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Generally, using the `throw` statement without using an exception object strikes me as poor practice for several reasons, including:

- Code designed to handle exceptions may be expecting an `Error` object, receiving a primitive may result in unexpected side effects or the inability to handle the exception without modifying the handling code.  An example of this is the lack of a `stack` property on the result from the throw expression.
- When not used in a try/catch statement, Internet Explorers 8 and lower will throw a different exception on your attempt to throw, with the message, *"Exception thrown and not caught"*<sup>*</sup>.  This can be even more confusing if you're debugging using the developer tools or have a global exception handler set to `window.onerror`.

So, yes, in general stick to properly throwing instances `Error` or its inheriting objects.

<sub>**nb, IE also does this for types of Error object that aren't constructed directly from `Error`. Yes, I know that's stupid, but they fixed it in IE 9 even though they told me it was "by design".*</sub>

Comment: `throw <String>` is an anti pattern merely for the reason that the returned error in `catch` doesn't have a `.stack` property if it's not a real `Error` instance and that's pure RAGE. As an aside, try/catch/throw is a general performance anti pattern in JS and should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building an AJAX app - exceptions may be not-so-useful. Due to asynchronous nature of ajax operations, error handling will not work as you may expect

```
function save_data(){
    try {
        ajax(some_ulr, function(){
            //callback
            do_wrong_thing();
        });
    } catch(e){
        handler_error();
    }
}
```

in above code snippet, error caused by do_wrong_thing will not trigger catch section.

Comment: Async code also breaks `return` though so that should kind of be expected...